# Proof of Dunford-Taylor formula in matrices cases

Tags: matrices

I have been reading Denis Serre's book  *Matrices Theory and Applications*(GTM216). In the proof of Dunford-Taylor formula in page 96, the author said that it is enough to assume $A=\lambda I+N,$ where $N$ is a nilpotent. I am confused since for any matrix $M$ defined on $\mathbb{C},$ it can decompose as  $M=D+N,$while $D$ is diagonalizable and $N$ is nilpotent, but the eigenvalues of $D$ are not necessarily all the same. So how can I assume $A=\lambda I+N?$

The following is proof of Dunford-Talyor formula, and the conjugation property is "$f(M^{-1}AM)=M^{-1}f(A)M$", the proposition 3.20 is "for matrix $M$ defined on $\mathbb{C}$,then $M$ decomposes as a sum $M=D+N,$ where $D$ is diagonalizable, $N$ is nilpotent, $DN=ND$ and spectrum of $D$ equals spectrum of $M$."

[image: Proof of Dunford-Taylor in Serre's book]
[image: Proposition 3.20 in Serre's book]

Comment: What is Proposition 3.20?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Idk why they say that, but $zI-D$ and $N$ commute, so you get a similar simple representation for $(zI-D-N)^{-1}=(zI-D)^{-1}+(zI-D)^{-2}N \dots$

Comment: I guess the author wants to treat the matrix formula blockwisely, since the Jordan canonical form of $A$ is composed of diagonal blocks $\lambda_j I+N_j,$ and the inverse $(zI_n-A)^{-1}$ is also keeping the diagonal blocks structure.